# Who are belongers and emulators?

Tags: meaning-in-context

As part of a lengthy description of its [Ideal Customer](http://www.mplans.com/remodeling_contractor_marketing_plan/ideal_customer_fc.php), a remodeling company says this:

> Our ideal customers are belongers and emulators - they entertain and love to have family around. A big draw for remodeling is to create space to entertain and host large family gatherings. They are very community-oriented and tend to participate heavily in school, religious, civic and nonprofit organizations.

So, who are *belongers* and *emulators*?

I couldn't find a suitable definition for either term on the Internet. Is an *emulator* someone who looks at something and then wants to have a similar thing? And is a *belonger* someone who belongs to a certain group?

Comment: Please cite the source.

Comment: The short answers are (probably) _yes_ and _mostly yes_. An _emulator_ evidently is another incarnation of the familiar early-adopter/keeper-up-with-the-Joneses who is so beloved of contractors, technology product makers, and anyone else who stands to gain from reckless consumerism. A _belonger_ seems to mean a member of many formal and informal organizations, groups, and collectives—in effect, a joiner who has already accomplished the joining part of the job.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's real marketing bullshit. It's almost a cliché of marketing "terms".

It just literally means the type of older, basically wealthy, couple who **belong** to clubs .. say the tennis club, or maybe the local Lions club.

The type that are really "part of the community" (belong" to the community).

By "emulators" - it's poorly used but the implication is they "Keep up with the Joneses" (I hope you know that phrase!)  They emulate expensive trends around town.

Note that, in fact, the top paragraphs of that page give some more explanation of their usage of "belongers".

So, it's just marketing bullshit for "rich, conservative people"

Comment: There are plenty of poor liberal people who are "belongers".

Comment: "The average project size with our ideal customer is $75,000."  Why talk in circles?  "belongers, emiulators" is marketing bullshit for "rich people so stupid they would pay $75,000 to have the latest color paint splashed on the plastic cupboard doors in their McMansion kitchen"

Comment: The same personality-type lingo could be used by a company selling relatively low-priced vinyl replacement windows. It is not intrinsically "rich, conservative people" who are targeted in this manner and to whom this typing refers.

Comment: I get your point -- sure.

Answer (score -1):

The author of the passage is tacking the -er ending (meaning "one who does *this*") onto the verb "belong".

A baker is one who bakes.

A singer is one who sings.

The belonger is one who, in general, belongs. That is, who prefers to belong to a group or feels most comfortable as part of a group. Emulators are those who attempt to be like others, to "follow the crowd" and do what other people do.

The answer to the question "Who are they?" is that the author is referring to a **personality type**, not to specific individuals.

Comment: It's specific marketing bullshit dude.  (Which you're lucky enough not to know.) In fact, it's explained at the top of the page.  it's like saying "d-drinkers" or "pink money" or whatever.

Comment: Mr Blow.  Marketers often use personality typing to identify their most likely customers. You, they'd want to sell a Dodge Hemi.

Comment: I so want one :O

Comment: Would it be red?